# Trying to redirect subdomains to non http but it's not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, multisite

I'm using this on a wordpress multisite to redirect my main domain to https and all subdomains to non https, however, it's only working for the main domain:

```
# for main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# for sub domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://subdomain.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

I've tried a couple of different things, and just can't seem to get the subdomain to redirect to http. :/ Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
# for main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# for sub domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Tried it, but got the same result. When going to 

    `https://sub.domain.com` it just gives me a privacy error instead of redirecting. :(

Comment: This is the working principle of the https. If you try to redirect to http, the user is informed by a security message.